# How to load an icon / png from Resources into a WPF control using properties window in VS15

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm migrating from using Windows Forms to using WPF and I am struggling to load icons for controls such as menu items and buttons. A lot of the solutions I see online are typing xaml code directly, however I was wondering if anyone could show me how it is intended to be done through the designer using the properties window?

I have loaded the image (i have both .ico and .png and can use either if this matters) into Resources. When I navigate to the control properties I can see an icon field. However I can't type anything directly into the text box and the further options only seem to be Custom Expression, System Resource and Create Data Binding. I have explored each option and it's not obvious how I would do this. I would expect to be able to use Local Resource but it's grayed out.

I have set the icon Build Action in Resources to 'Resource'.

I much prefer using the designer property window to typing the xaml directly, especially as I am just starting out. If someone could show me a way this can be done I'd be very appreciative as I've spent far too long just trying to get a simple image to be displayed beside a menuitem.

Thanks.